# How more than one engineers can code on a single machine

Tags: server, files, remote

We have ubuntu 12.4 (Desktop Version) running on our server and four engineers (2 using windows and 2 using ubuntu).
Is it possible for all of them to code on the same package on the server directly from their machine (remotely) ... Is there a tool to create a remote working terminal for each of them or maybe using file sharing etc ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use a revision control system such as `bzr` or `git`, for your source code. Then everyone can work independently and merge there changes into the central repository. There are also [commercial contracts](https://launchpad.net/+tour/join-launchpad#commercial) available for https://launchpad.net/ for hosting private projects if you'd prefer to contract out maintaining such services.

Comment: Thanks, we plan to use subversion (git) via bitbucket or github ... But we want to avoid the scenario where ... each engineer would have to configure the codes on their machine ...

Comment: But if there isn't a better way ... we would adopt git .... thanks for your contribution

Comment: version control software is the industry best-practice, you won't find any "better" method.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a nx-server on a machine and access it remotly with nx-client. This will allow you to setup a good development plattform which can be accessed from any OS from anywhere.

Still, sharing the working sourcecode is a absolute no-go. Invest the time to setup git or at least svn. This **will** become a hugh timesaver in less than a month. I use git even when I work locally on my hobby projects.